# How to customize with css special characters like comma , vertical bar, point and so on?

Tags: filter, css, stylesheet

[image]

For example I want to have all commas (*or whatever other characters like this:* " `/, |, &, $` *and so on* " ) from a text in different colors.

Is this possible?!

Answer (score 1):

You could use spans to separate the commas or ampersand from the rest of the text

`<p> Some text <span style="color:pink">/</span> Some text ....</p>`

I don't think is yet possible using only css

In PHP you could theme your text with preg_replace to add the spans around the comma, ampersand, slash, etc.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

or str_replace

```
<?php str_replace(',', '<span class="pink">,</span>', $string); ?>
```

For wordpress add the suggested code to your template file, for more info about templating see:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

Comment: I would like to do this without classes, spans etc, only with css.

Comment: @Blanka, you simply cannot do this with CSS alone. You need to wrap characters in elements, manually or server-side or client-side.

Comment: This is a JS/jQuery problem and it will require a lot of escaping characters.

Comment: I'll use this in Wordpress. Is possible to add a filter in functions.php to do that ?

Comment: I'm used to when making changes to the whole site to use the themes template file (comming from drupal here), I've edited my answer prividing you with a link about template files in wordpress.

Comment: Actually this is possible with CSS alone but browser support is pretty shallow at the moment. Check out this [video] (http://vimeo.com/channels/cssday/69531448) with Eric Meyer (c.19:00 mark) about swapping fonts based on unicode ranges.

Answer (score 0):

**This do the thing:**

```
add_filter('the_content', 'testfilter');

function testfilter($content) {

    $pattern = ' | '; //search content for ' | ' string
    $replacement = '<span class="test">' . $pattern . '</span>'; //replace it with the same term but inside a span
    $replaced = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    return $replaced;

}
```

**Credits goes here:** *http://wordpress.org/support/topic/str_replace-content-with-a-span-class*